# AppleScript Opening iCloud Documents

Tags: terminal, icloud, finder, applescript, numbers

I am trying to write an AppleScript to open a Numbers document, which is stored in the Numbers folder on my iCloud drive, so that I can access a cell value and create a reminder with it (or otherwise notify myself of this value).

When I try to access the file directly using the symlink to my iCloud I created in my home folder, Numbers says the file doesn't exist.

I found the following on a blog post, though I am not sure I am using it right.

```
set the defaultDestinationFolder to "/Users/luketimothy/Desktop"
set filePath to "/Users/luketimothy/Library/" & "Mobile Documents:com~apple~Numbers:Documents:Budget.numbers"


tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    try
        open filePath
    on error

    end try
end tell
```

This script also results in a "file doesn't exist" error.

I tried copying the file into my Documents folder, but I got the same error (and the file doesn't show up in the Documents folder in finder either, even though if I try to copy it again I am asked if I wish to overwrite)

I can't seem to access the Numbers folder in my iCloud folder from the terminal either, which might allow me to use pwd to get an absolute path.

What can I do? Is there some restriction on access to this Numbers folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re trying to define the filePath variable by combining a Posix path string with an HFS string.

Try defining the filePath variable like this…

```
set filePath to (path to library folder from user domain as text) & ¬
    "Mobile Documents:com~apple~Numbers:Documents:Budget.numbers"

tell application "Numbers"
    open alias filePath
end tell
```

**OR.. My Personal Preference**

```
property theDocument : "Budget.numbers"

set filePath to ((path to library folder from user domain as text) & ¬
    "Mobile Documents:com~apple~Numbers:Documents:" & theDocument)

tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists of alias filePath) then
        tell current application to display dialog "The File: " & theDocument & ¬
            " Does Not Exist" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK"
        return
    end if
end tell

tell application "Numbers"
    open alias filePath
end tell
```

If you’re not quite sure how to correctly define a file path, you can always use the following Apple Script code in a separate script editor document to correctly retrieve the file paths

```
set filePathAsAlias to (choose file with prompt "choose file") -- Returns The File Path As An Alias
```

**OR**

```
set posixPathOffilePath to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "choose file") -- Returns The POSIX Path Of The File
```

Comment: A slightly more preferable way to reference the user's library folder would be `path to the library folder from the user domain [as text]` where `as text` is optional in case one just wants the (HFS) file path instead of the default `alias` object.

Comment: @CJK Great suggestion and this way it’s not “hard coded” with the exception of the actual file name (which could be set in a separate variable and that variable added to the filePath variable)

Comment: @wch1zpink is `(path to library folder from user domain as text)` literally what I enter? I found this code like this and thought I was supposed to replace it with a path...

Comment: @Luke . The AppleScript code I posted is exactly how you need it to be